# Display as input options after entering with mechanicalsoup - Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanicalsoup

I search a solution for this case:

I use mechanicalsoup for into a web:

```
import mechanicalsoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

browser.open("http://webinto.com/into/")

browser.select_form('form[action=""]')
browser["user"] ="user1"
browser["password"] ="password1"

browser.submit_selected()

print(browser.get_current_page())
```

And i see a list of applications:

```
<td width="394px">
<img alt="" height="16" src="authorizator/vineta.item.gif" title="" width="16"/>
<form action="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" name="f0">
<input name="token" type="hidden" value="123456"/>
<input name="sign" type="hidden" value="7890="/>
<input name="system" type="hidden" value="Application_1"/>
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="GO_SYSTEM"/><h1><a href="javascript: document.f0.submit()">Application 1</a></h1>
<div id="desc0"><h2>Application 1</h2></div>
</form>
</td>
<td width="12px"></td>
<td width="394px">
<img alt="" height="16" src="authorizator/vineta.item.gif" title="" width="16"/>
<form action="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" name="f1">
<input name="token" type="hidden" value="123456"/>
<input name="sign" type="hidden" value="7890"/>
<input name="system" type="hidden" value="Application_2"/>
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="GO_SYSTEM"/><h1><a href="javascript: document.f1.submit()">Application 2</a></h1>
<div id="desc1"><h2>Application 2</h2></div>
</form>
</td>
```

And i need to see the list of applications as options to enter, such as:

```
Press the number of the application to enter:
1.- Application 1
2.- Application 2
3.- Application 3
```

Thanks!

Comment: `browser.get_current_page()` returns the page seen as a BeautifulSoup object, and you can iterate over this object (see the doc of BeautifulSoup) to fetch all `<h2>` tags, and call `print` on their content.

Comment: I try this: print(browser.get_current_page().find_all('h2')) but i need see the h2 how options for into. 
If i need to enter h2: 1 press 1 and enter web 1 if i want to enter h2: 2 press 2 and enter web 2.